# Why are my magnolia leaves turning color?

Tags: magnolia

This is a magnolia tree we planted last spring.  It's about 5' tall.

We watered it faithfully all last summer and gave it three our four doses of compost tea, sort of monthly.   Over the winter and early spring, some deer ate a few of the buds and so it didn't bloom.  I watered it today because it was very hot and I noticed the leaves are taking on a reddish-orange tint.

[image]

Is this a normal color?  If not, what can be done to help?  We live in hardiness zone 5a, and three tree gets plenty of sun.

Comment: I wonder if it's a touch of sunburn.

Comment: What's that?  Plants get sunburn?

Comment: They sure can..

Comment: Perhaps you could explain in more detail?

Comment: Did you try an internet search?  Here is an article to get you started: https://www.gardeners.com/how-to/plant-stress/7341.html